# How do you capture part of a regex to a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know about `"string"[/regex/]`, which returns the part of the string that matches. But what if I want to return only the *captured* part(s) of a string?

I have the string `"1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"`. I want to store in the variable `title` the text `The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring`.

I can capture this part with the regex `/\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i`. But writing the Ruby `"1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"[/\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i]` returns `0_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3` which isn't what I want.

I can get what I want by writing

```
"1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3" =~ /\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i
title = $~.captures[0]
```

But this seems sloppy. Surely there's a proper way to do this?

(I'm aware that someone can probably write a simpler regex to target the text I want that lets the `"string"[/regex/]` method work, but this is just an example to illustrate the problem, the specific regex isn't the issue.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass number of part to `[/regexp/, index]` method:

```
=> string = "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
=> string[/\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i, 1]
=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"
=> string[/\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i, 0]
=> "0_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `match` method:

```
string = "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
regexp = /\d_(?!.*\d_)(.*).mp3$/i

matches = regexp.match(string)
matches[1]
#=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"
```

Where `matches[0]` would return the whole match and `matches[1]` (and following) returns all subcaptures:

```
matches.to_a    
#=> ["0_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3", "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"]
```

Read more examples: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D

Answer (score 1):

You can use *named captures*

```
"1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3" =~ /\d_(?!.*\d_)(?<title>.*).mp3$/i
```

and `$~[:title]` will give you want you want

Answer (score 1):

Meditate on this:

Here's the source string to be parsed:

```
str = "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
```

Patterns can be defined as strings:

```
DATE_REGEX = '\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}'
SERIAL_REGEX = '\d{2}'
TITLE_REGEX = '.+'
```

Then interpolated into a regexp:

```
regex = /^(#{ DATE_REGEX })_(#{ SERIAL_REGEX })_(#{ TITLE_REGEX })/
# => /^(\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})_(\d{2})_(.+)/
```

The advantage to that is it's easier to maintain because the pattern is really several smaller ones.

```
str.match(regex) # => #<MatchData "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3" 1:"1952-FEB-21" 2:"70" 3:"The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3">
regex.match(str) # => #<MatchData "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3" 1:"1952-FEB-21" 2:"70" 3:"The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3">
```

are equivalent because both [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-match) and [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-match) implement `match`.

We can retrieve what was captured as an array:

```
regex.match(str).captures # => ["1952-FEB-21", "70", "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"]
regex.match(str).captures.last # => "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
```

We can also name the captures and access them like we would a hash:

```
regex = /^(?<date>#{ DATE_REGEX })_(?<serial>#{ SERIAL_REGEX })_(?<title>#{ TITLE_REGEX })/
matches = regex.match(str)
matches[:date] # => "1952-FEB-21"
matches[:serial] # => "70"
matches[:title] # => "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
```

Of course, it's not necessary to mess with that rigamarole at all. We can [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-split) the string on underscores ('`_`'):

```
str = "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
str.split('_') # => ["1952-FEB-21", "70", "The", "Case", "of", "the", "Gold", "Ring.mp3"]
```

`split` can take a limit parameter saying how many times it should split the string. Passing in `3` gives us:

```
str.split('_', 3) # => ["1952-FEB-21", "70", "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"]
```

Grabbing the last element returns:

```
str.split('_', 3).last # => "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easiest to use a capture group here, but I'd like to present some possibilities that do not, for illustrative purposes. All employ the same positive lookahead (`(?=\.mp3$)`). all but one use a positive lookbehind and one uses `\K` to "forget" the match up to the last character before beginning of the desired match. Some permit the matched string to contain digits (`.+`); others do not (`[^\d]`).

```
str = "1952-FEB-21_70_The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring.mp3"

1 # match follows last digit followed by underscore, cannot contain digits 
str[/(?<=\d_)[^\d]+(?=\.mp3$)/]    
  #=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"

2 # same as 1, as `\K` disregards match to that point
str[/\d_\K[^\d]+(?=\.mp3$)/]
  #=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"

3 # match follows underscore, two digits, underscore, may contain digits 
str[/(?<=_\d\d_).+(?=\.mp3$)/]
  #=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"

4 # match follows string having specfic pattern, may contain digits
str[/(?<=\d{4}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}_\d{2}_).+(?=\.mp3$)/]
  #=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"

5 # match follows digit, any 12 characters, another digit and underscore,
  # may contain digits
str[/(?<=\d.{12}\d_).+(?=\.mp3$)/]
  #=> "The_Case_of_the_Gold_Ring"
```